# javascript to dynamically populate dropdown with an array from value typed into text field

Tags: javascript, dynamic, textbox, drop-down-menu

Hi I have a code example available here: http://jsbin.com/oxoweh

My problem is that I cannot get the value that is being entered into the textbox so that when the select button is clicked the second dropdown will display only the data related to what was entered into the text box. for example if fruits is entered into the textbox I want to have the subcat dropdown have all fruits in it instead of using the existing category dropdown menu

Comment: You mean `var x = document.getElemebtById('fruit'); var v = x.val;` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/goldentoa11/P3hs8/1/

I added a parameter to your "SelectSubCat()" called txtValue. This is so you can pass the value you want to compare against.

You'll need to call the "SelectSubCat()" function with the text field's value when you call it. I added an id to the text field called "selectText", and when I click the button I had added

```
onclick="SelectSubCat(document.getElementById('selectText').value)"
```

and this will call the function with the text of the input. Then instead of using the value from the form, it uses the value passed to it, and creates the appropriate sub category. Lastly, you need to change the Category's "onchange" function to just pass an empty string.

```
function SelectSubCat(txtValue) {

if(txtValue == "") txtValue = document.drop_list.Category.value;
// This line is to set txtValue to Category's value if the current value is blank. 
// In other words, if it was called by changing the dropdown, 
// give it the drop down's value.

// ON selection of category this function will work
removeAllOptions(document.drop_list.SubCat);
addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "", "SubCat", "");

if (txtValue == 'Fruits') {
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "Mango", "Mango");
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "Banana", "Banana");
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "Orange", "Orange");
}
if (txtValue == 'Games') {
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "Cricket", "Cricket");
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "Football", "Football");
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "Polo", "Polo", "");
}
if (txtValue == 'Scripts') {
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "PHP", "PHP");
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "ASP", "ASP");
    addOption(document.drop_list.SubCat, "Perl", "Perl");
}

}
```

Comment: Hi it doesn't populate the subcategory list when I type in the txtValue in the text field it only works with when I select something from the category drop-down menu.

Comment: did you follow the jsfiddle link? I have it working there. 

edit: oops, didn't realize that enter posts the comment. Anyways, make sure that you add an id of 'selectText' to your textfield, and then you add an onclick to your button like the code I posted. It should work.